# how to execute the JS before rendering the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am writing a html page,in which i fire a ajax request and then check the response i receive from it and depending upon the response,i decide whether to render the page or not.At present depending upon the request,i am redirecting to another url but html page gets rendered.

Comment: You need to write server-side code.  By the time you're on the client, it's too late.

Comment: post you related codes to

Comment: server side would be better, but, you can call your js code before your html and then render whichever html based on the js code path.

Comment: @Johan How are you going to remove html that hasn't been added yet?

Comment: Why send it to the client if you don't need it? If you really have to, you could send an synchronous XMLHttpRequest, but you should avoid that at all costs

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a pre-HTML effort.  Your logic will have to be server side.
You could however create a 'blank' page which redirects to content or shows content.  You will be fully loading elements tho needed to act on this logic (JS / HTML code, etc;)

**Workflow would be:**

1. Load blank looking page with JS logic
2. Identify if you should be loading content or denying further access

Answer (score 1):

If your page has a single container element, you could apply `style="display: none;"` inline style to it, and then optionally remove that if you want to display the page.